# How to bulk insert and validate data against existing database data

Tags: sql-server, linq, csv, linq-to-sql, webforms

Here is my situation, my client wants to bulk insert 100,000+ rows into the database from a csv file which is simple enough but the values need to be checked against data that is already in the database (does this product type exist? is this product still sold? etc.). To make things worse these files will also be uploaded into the live system during the day so I need to make sure I’m not locking any tables for long. The data that is inserted will also be spread across multiple tables.

I’ve been adding the date into a staging table which takes seconds, I then tried creating a WebService to start processing the table using Linq and marking any erroneous rows with an invalid flag (this can take some time). Once the validation is done I need take the valid rows and update/add the rows to the appropriate tables.

Is there a process for this that I am unfamiliar with?

Comment: SSIS?.................

Comment: Looks like Ill look into SSIS

Comment: TSQL MERGE statement?

Answer (score 0):

For a smaller dataset I would suggest

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE....) 
UPDATE (blah) 
ELSE 
INSERT (blah)
```

You could do this in chunks to avoid server load, but this is by no means a quick solution, so SSIS would be preferable